# Referring Javascript Instance Variable from Constructor without using 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm just started with JavaScript oops concept , I want to access 3 instance variable from a constructor with out 'this' keyword, First value is coming but not 2nd.. and so on ..    `

```
        function CreateObject()
        {
            var p1 = new person('chanky',25,'Male');           
        }

        function person(name,age,sex)
        {
            this.name = name; 
            this.age = age;
            this.sex = sex;      

            document.write(name); //Working
            document.write(age); //not Working
            document.write(sex); //not Working

         /*If we use 'this' keyword then all are Working */

            document.write(this.name); // Working
            document.write(this.age); // Working
            document.write(this.sex); // Working
        }`
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: when you are ommiting 'this' then you refer to argument of person function and with 'this' to instance property. you cannot mix these two to refer always to instance property

Comment: You don't refer instance variables, you refer **constructor arguments** (`name,age,sex`), this is not the same

Comment: but that works...[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06w6uen7/)

Comment: It work for me in both cases.

Comment: `document.write(name)` Do not use this on this occasion, use `console.log()` or `alert` instead to test. `document.write` will destroy your page.

Comment: Also your code should be working just fine, age and sex should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with 'this'? You want to access a member that you not declared, so you use 'this'.

You can access the values outside the class like this:

```
var p = new person('chanky',25,'Male');
alert (p.age);

function person(name,age,sex)
        {
            this.name = name; 
            this.age = age;
            this.sex = sex;      
        }
```

If you're still worried about, declare a variable and assign the values you've received to them, and as you're using an OO approach, encapsulate the variables to access them outside of your class

```
function person(name,age,sex)
        {
            var _name;
            var _age;
            var _sex;

            _name = name; 
            _age = age;
            _sex = sex;      

            this.getName = function () {
                return _name;
            };

            this.getAge = function () {
                return _age;
            };

            this.getSex = function () {
                return _sex;
            };
        }
```

And use the 'methods':

```
var p2 = new person('chanky',25,'Male');
alert (p2.getAge());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the jsbin.. https://jsbin.com/teyupuhele/edit?html,js,output

This is best practice for OOP...

```js
function person(name, age, sex) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.sex = sex;


};

// create p1 instance of object person

var p1 = new person('chanky', 22, 'Male');

console.log(p1.name); //Working
console.log(p1.age); //Working
console.log(p1.sex); //Working
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there Chanky this should work fine

I have just created a jsFiddle to show using console.log

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hq4ebs2d/

Javascript

```
function person(name, age, sex) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;

    console.log(name); //Working
    console.log(age); //not Working
    console.log(sex); //not Working

    /*If we use 'this' keyword then all are Working */

    console.log(this.name); // Working
    console.log(this.age); // Working
    console.log(this.sex); // Working
};

var p1 = new person('chanky', 25, 'Male');
```

Just one quick note you have }` at the end of your code, make sure to change that to };